# Windows 7 users can't access some share folders

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

I just migrated users to Windows 7 Enterprise x64 from Windows XP Pro. Now Win7 users can't access or map some share folders. When they log in to Windows XP they can access all shares without problem so access rights are ok. I know that could be problem with our GPO setting but I don't know even where to start. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You mean remotely? The shared folders are on another PC?

Comment: yep the share folders are on server

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want,
1) Right click on the network icon in your taskbar

[image: Click on Network & Sharing Center]

2) Click on Open Network & Sharing Center

[image: Click on JOINED]

3) Click on Joined

[image: Lick on Change What you want to share....]

4)Click on Change what you're sharing with the *Network Type* and set permissions to the folders.

Answer (score 0):

I have added DNS suffix to domain where is share and this fixed this problem :)